# editing the value of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT thru bash script

Tags: grub

I want to append `fastboot` to the end of the existing value of the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable in /etc/default/grub not manually, but by using bash script and `echo` command. The problem is that initial values of this variable are different on different machines so I don't know which searching algorithm to use to locate where the value of the variable ends. I want to be shown how to append `fastboot` directly to the existing value.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408685/309736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea how to that in pure bash but typically a search and replace would call either on `awk` or `sed`.

```
sed -i 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.*/& fastboot/'  /etc/default/grub
```

`-i` : do in in-place replacement

Followed by the search and replace syntax `s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/`

`^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.*` : a REGular EXPression that matches on the line(s) starting `^` with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT  and any number of characters after that string: `.*`

`& fastboot` : the REPLACEMENT string where the unescaped `&` character references the
whole matched portion of the pattern space (i.e. whatever the REGEXP matched,in this example: the whole line) and append `fastboot`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and got ` sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: Of course, your shell will interpret the `&` as a background signal, edited accordingly by enclosing the `s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/` in ticks `'s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/'`

Comment: Dear HBruijn! Big thanks again for help. May I ask just for another assistance. How can I put fastboot inside the value. Now it is appended after the value. I mean now I get `VAR="quiet splash" fastboot`

Comment: Match differently! Don't match the whole line but for instance only match  on REGEXP `/^VAR="/` and REPLACE with `/&fastboot /`